# Create local business application for Facebook

Tags: facebook

My wife is starting her local business, and I would like to develop a booking application that users can use to book appointments with. Is this feasible using the facebook development tools? I tried to overview the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com but I came out with no clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

What is a Facebook app?

In layman terms, it's just a window to your actual app with a bonus that you can use Facebook's social data with it. So, yes! Basically, you can pretty much do anything with it. Plus, if you are looking forward to create an app for a local business, I would recommend taking a look at `page tabs` from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs/).

Here is how a Facebook app works:

1. You create an app on your server.
2. You give it's url to Facebook (called the `canvas url`).
3. You specify the dimensions.

And that's it! Your app is up and running!

Comment: If I only want this app for a specific Local Business, is that possible? Or will the app be available to ANYONE that wast to include it in "their app"? Looks promising :)

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by "their app". Please clarify.

Comment: Can I keep a facebook app only for one specific person? Or will apps be available to anyone if I put it in the Facebook App Store?

Comment: If you want an app for one person only, then why use Facebook?

Comment: Ok, I'm confusing :) Target is to build a booking app that ONLY will be available at my wifes Local Business page. The facebook users could book their appointment and see the availability in the calendar. Of course the app could be used by anyone, but I don't want the app available to any other Local Business (for now :))...

Comment: Ah! Then **page tabs** is exactly the thing you're looking for. It's page specific, it isn't published as a Facebook app. That is, the app is functional on the page itself and only the page viewers can use it.